# Integration of arcsine

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $$8\int^{1}_{0}(\arcsin x)^3dx$$

Do I substitute $u$ for $\arcsin x$, or do I go straight to parts with $u=8(\arcsin x)^3$ and $dv=dx$?

Any nod in the right direction would help.

Comment: Or first rearrange the equation to $8(\sqrt{1-x^2})^3xdx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $u = \arcsin x$ then $du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx$ and $x = \sin u $. Thus

$$8\int_0^{\pi/2} u^3\cos u \,\,du \underbrace {=}_{\text{by parts}} \ldots $$

**Spoiler:**

> $$\begin{align}\require{cancel}\int_0^{\pi/2} u^3\cos u \,\,du &=8\Bigg [u^3\sin u \Bigg|_0^{\pi/2} - 3\Bigg[\cancel{u^2\cos u \Bigg|_0^{\pi/2}}^{\color{red}0} + 2 \Bigg[u \sin u\Bigg|_0^{\pi/2} - \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin u \,du\Bigg]\Bigg]\Bigg]\\&=8\Bigg[\frac{\pi^3}{8} - 6 \Bigg[\frac{\pi}{2} -1\Bigg]\Bigg]\\&=\color{#05f}{ 48 - 24\pi +\pi^3}\end{align}$$

Comment: $\int^{1}_{0}8(u)^3\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, then let $x=sinu$, $dx=cosudu$ to $\int^{\pi/2}_{0}8u^3\sqrt{1-sin^2x}cosudu$, doesn't that turn into another cosu, and what happens to the 8?

Comment: It's just a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Sub $x=\sin{u}$, $dx = \cos{u} du$.  Then the integral is

$$8 \int_0^{\pi/2} du \, u^3 \cos{u} $$

A few integration by parts and you'll be there.  I get $\pi^3-24 \pi+48$.